# Solving $\frac{\cos5x \;\cos3x-\sin3x\;\sin x}{\cos2x}=1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

What is general solution of $$\cfrac{\cos5x \;\cos3x-\sin3x\;\sin x}{\cos2x}=1$$
$$1)\frac{k\pi}3\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad2)\frac{k\pi}2\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad3)\frac{2k\pi}5\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad4)\frac{2k\pi}3$$

The numerator of the fraction is $\cos(5x+3x)$. so I should find general solution of $\cos8x=\cos2x$. I'm not sure how to do it, I can write $\cos8x $ in term of $\cos 2x$:

$$\cos8x=2\cos^24x-1=2(2\cos^22x-1)^2-1$$
After substituting it in the equation and using $\cos2x=t$ we have degree four equation . Is there easier way to do it?

Comment: How is the numerator $\cos(5x+3x)$???

Comment: I think your argument of sine might be off. Do you mean $\sin(5x)$ instead of $\sin(x)$?

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore isn't it $\cos(\alpha+\beta)=\cos\alpha\cos\beta-\sin\alpha\sin\beta$ ?

Comment: @Soheil ofcourse but I dont see the 5x on sin!

Comment: Oh I didn't care enough to angles

Comment: Please clarify on whether there is a typo in the statement of the problem as suggested by @Clayton

Comment: @openproblem there is no typo in the question I just messed up in answering it;)

Comment: Maybe there is typo in original question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$0=\cos5x \;\cos3x-\sin3x\;\sin x-\cos 2x$$ $$=\cos5x \;\cos3x-\sin3x\;\sin x-\cos (5x-3x)$$ $$=\sin 3x\sin 5x-\sin 3x\sin x$$ $$\to -2\sin ^2 3x\cos 2x=0$$ Can you finish it?

Note that $\cos 2x\neq 0$ has to be included(why?)  $$\to \sin 3x=0$$

Answer (score 3):

$$\cos (5 x) \cos (3 x)-\sin (3 x) \sin (x)=\cos (2 x)$$
$$\frac{1}{2} (\cos (2 x)+\cos (8 x))-\frac{1}{2} (\cos (2 x)-\cos (4 x))=\cos(2x)$$
$$\frac{1}{2} (\cos (4 x)+\cos (8 x))-\cos(2x)=0$$
$$\cos (8 x)+\cos (4 x)-2 \cos (2 x)=0$$
$$2 \cos (2 x) \cos (6 x)-2 \cos (2 x)=0$$
$$\cos(2x)\left[\cos(6x)-1\right]=0$$
$$\cos(2x)=0\to x=\pm\frac{\pi}{4}+k\pi$$
discarded because this solution will make zero the denominator of the original equation
$$\cos(6x)=1\to x=\frac{k\pi}{3}$$

Comment: $\cos 2x$ cannot be zero as expression will be undefined!

Comment: Right! Thank you @AlbusDumbledore

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Using [Werner Formulas](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/WernerFormulas.html),

$$2\cos2x=2\cos5x\cos3x-2\sin3x\sin x=\cos2x+\cos8x-(\cos2x-\cos4x)$$

Now use [Prosthaphaeresis](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html) Formulas $$\cos8x+\cos4x=2\cos6x\cos2x$$

Hope you can take it from here?